# Change icon depending on file extension

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I got a question whether it is possible to change the icon of parent node if the child contains a specific file extension.

Let me explain myself by some code. I have the following setup:

```
<span class="file">
  <a href="../someurl/print.pdf" class="">Print PDF</a>
</span>
<span class="file">
  <a href="../someurl/test.pdf" class="">Test PDF</a>
</span>
<p>
Should show up a word icon
</p>
<span class="file">
  <a href="../someurl/word-test.docx" class="">Word document</a>
</span>
```

With the following CSS:

```
span.file{
  background: url('https://static.spiceworks.com/images/how_to_steps/0005/9590/8a544ad4a4ee8c8b164ff38a3f700f5a35f3805cbf7f27d8ec0bb4e455e5dab1_icpdf.gif') 0 0 no-repeat;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 20px;
  display: block;
}
 span.file a[href$=".docx"] {
  background: url('http://image.chromefans.org/fileicons/format/docx.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Is it possible to change the background of the `<span>` depending on the file extension? As can been seen in the demo below the Word icon is generated but it does not replace the current PDF icon.

Please keep in mind that I can not change the HTML due to the fact that the HTML is rendered through a module within DNN. Therefore I need a solution that is pure CSS only or perhaps with some help of Javascript.

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/kp4yxf4v/)

Comment: Does it need to set the icon on the `span`? Can't it set it on `a` instead?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p7r91bbs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `background-image` on `anchor` instead of `span`. [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kp4yxf4v/3/)

```css
span.file {
  display: block;
  padding: 1px 0px;
}
span.file a[href$=".docx"] {
  background: url('http://image.chromefans.org/fileicons/format/docx.png') left center no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
span.file a[href$=".pdf"] {
  background: url('https://static.spiceworks.com/images/how_to_steps/0005/9590/8a544ad4a4ee8c8b164ff38a3f700f5a35f3805cbf7f27d8ec0bb4e455e5dab1_icpdf.gif') left center no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="file">
  <a href="../someurl/print.pdf" class="">Print PDF</a>
</span>
<span class="file">
  <a href="../someurl/test.pdf" class="">Test PDF</a>
</span>
<p>
  Should show up a word icon
</p>
<span class="file">
  <a href="../someurl/word-test.docx" class="">Word document</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The fiddle I saw was displaying pdf icons for the pdf files and both a pdf and a word icon for the docx files. Also, because you are adding the icon to the  element, you need to pad THAT and not the the  element.

This seems to work:

```
span.file a{
  padding: 1px 0 1px 20px;
  display: block;
}
 span.file a[href$=".docx"] {
  background: url('http://image.chromefans.org/fileicons/format/docx.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

span.file a[href$=".pdf"] {
   background: url('https://static.spiceworks.com/images/how_to_steps/0005/9590/8a544ad4a4ee8c8b164ff38a3f700f5a35f3805cbf7f27d8ec0bb4e455e5dab1_icpdf.gif') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use some Javascript / jQuery, as there is no way to go up the DOM with just CSS to apply the class to the `span`. Here is a solution using a little jQuery to accomplish what you are after:

http://codepen.io/mikehdesign/pen/EyZdRm

**HTML**

```
<span class="file">
  <a href="../someurl/print.pdf" class="">Print PDF</a>
</span>
<span class="file">
  <a href="../someurl/test.pdf" class="">Test PDF</a>
</span>
<p>
Should show up a word icon
</p>
<span class="file">
  <a href="../someurl/word-test.docx">Word document</a>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
span.file{
  background: url('https://static.spiceworks.com/images/how_to_steps/0005/9590/8a544ad4a4ee8c8b164ff38a3f700f5a35f3805cbf7f27d8ec0bb4e455e5dab1_icpdf.gif') 0 0 no-repeat;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 20px;
  display: block;
}

span.file.word {
  background: url('http://image.chromefans.org/fileicons/format/docx.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("a[href$='pdf']").parent('span').addClass('pdf');

$("a[href$='docx']").parent('span').addClass('word');
```

As identified in other posts, if you are ok with applying the background to the `a` instead you can just use CSS

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood you, but this works in Chrome. Just set the original .file on the `a` instead of `span`.

```css
span.file a {
  padding: 1px 0 1px 20px;
  display: block;
}
 span.file a[href$=".docx"] {
  /* Overwrite background */
  background: url('http://image.chromefans.org/fileicons/format/docx.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

 span.file a[href$=".pdf"] {
    background: url('https://static.spiceworks.com/images/how_to_steps/0005/9590/8a544ad4a4ee8c8b164ff38a3f700f5a35f3805cbf7f27d8ec0bb4e455e5dab1_icpdf.gif') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

 span.file a[href$=".xls"] {
  /* Overwrite background */
  background: url('http://image.chromefans.org/fileicons/format/xls.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<span class="file">
  <a href="../someurl/print.pdf" class="">Print PDF</a>
</span>
<span class="file">
  <a href="../someurl/test.pdf" class="">Test PDF</a>
</span>
<p>
Should show up a word icon
</p>
<span class="file">
  <a href="../someurl/word-test.docx" class="">Word document</a>
</span>
<span class="file">
  <a href="../someurl/excel-test.xls" class="">Excel document</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
span.file a[href$=".pdf"]{
  background: url('https://static.spiceworks.com/images/how_to_steps/0005/9590/8a544ad4a4ee8c8b164ff38a3f700f5a35f3805cbf7f27d8ec0bb4e455e5dab1_icpdf.gif') 0 0 no-repeat;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 20px;
  display: block;
}
 span.file a[href$=".docx"] {
  background: url('http://image.chromefans.org/fileicons/format/docx.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
   padding: 1px 0 1px 20px;
}
```